# Run-Time error '-2147217871 (80040e31)': Query timeout expired

Tags: excel, odbc, teradata

This error comes up when I try and run this big query. Smaller query's it doesn't. I have set connect timeout to 0 and that doesn't help. It looks like the connect makes it and it gets hung up at the .Open part of the code. Thank you for any help.

```
Public Sub dbConnectTDaY()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rec_set As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim MyConn, varSQL As String
    Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long, c As Long
    Dim MyField, Location As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strStDt As String
    Dim strEnDt As String
    strStDt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xxx").Range("B6").Value
    strEnDt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("xxx").Range("B5").Value
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Rec_set = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set Location = [A2]
        Rw = Location.Row
        Col = Location.Column
        c = Col

    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT gp.cnt"
    strSQL = strSQL & ",gp.pod"
    strSQL = strSQL & ",gp.grp_paddsa"
    strSQL = strSQL & ",gp.grp_rasdd"
   '  etc.........



    cn.ConnectionTimeout = 0 'To wait till the query finishes without generating error

    cn.Open "DSN=#EDWP;Databasename=INTY;Uid=XXXXX;Pwd=XXXXX;"


    If cn.State = adStateOpen Then 'If connection is success, continue 'Check for errors...

        Rec_set.Open strSQL, cn 'Issue SQL statement
        For i = 0 To Rec_set.Fields.Count - 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Rec_set.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        Do Until Rec_set.EOF
            For Each MyField In Rec_set.Fields
                Cells(Rw, c) = MyField
                c = c + 1
            Next MyField
            Rec_set.MoveNext
            Rw = Rw + 1
            c = Col
        Loop
    End If
     Rec_set.Close
    cn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

`cn.ConnectionTimeout = 0` only effects the timeout on the connection.

You want to set the  `CommandTimeout` also.

Comment: Thanks. That answered it

Comment: I am still getting error when I have put command timeout in. Can anyone help?